# Create a new table with rows of only checked checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML table with a checkbox in each row.
I want to loop over the table and if there are any checkboxes that are checked. 
I need to create a new table with rows of only checked checkboxes.

Any advice will be appreciated!
I know how to go through the table. But how to store HTML code of that row in the variable?

```
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
    var $tr = $(this);
    if ($tr.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {

    }
});
```

What I am trying to do is to send new table to a new page.

```
    function toView(){
    var newWindow = window.open();      
    var newHTML = '<html><head></head><body><table>';
    var endHtml = '</table></body></html>';


     $('table tbody tr').each(function() {
        var $tr = $(this);
        if ($tr.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {

           // what suppose to be here....

        }
      });
    newHTML = new_table + endHtml
    newWindow.document.write(newHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way!

```
function toView(){
    var newWindow = window.open();      
    var HTML_head = '<html><head></head><body><table>';
    var HTML_footer = '</table></body></html>';
    var new_HTML_page = "";
    var new_table = "";
    var html = "";

    $('table tbody tr input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
        html = $(this).closest("tr").clone().find('tr:last').remove().end().prop('outerHTML');
        new_table += html;     
    });         
    newHTML = HTML_head + new_table + HTML_footer;
    newWindow.document.write(newHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it, If you want to create a table with its conents:

```
$(function() {
    var newWindow = $('#window');
    $('table tbody tr input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
        var $tr = $(this).parents('tr');
        var $new_table = $('<table>').append($tr);
        newWindow.append($new_table);
    });
});
```

[Test it here](https://jsfiddle.net/fsL9mwqb/)

Comment: Sorry but it returns just [object Object]. Here is my full function:
 function toView(){
  var newWindow = window.open();  
  var newHTML = '<html><head></head><body><table>';
  var endHtml = '</table></body></html>';
  var $new_table=""
  
  $('table tbody tr input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
     var $tr_contents = $(this).parents('tr');
     $new_table = $('<table>').html($tr_contents);
  }); 
  newHTML = $new_table + endHtml
  newWindow.document.write(newHTML);
 }

Comment: ... newHTML = $new_table.html() + endHtml; newWindow.document.write(newHTML);
should work

Comment: It takes the row with only last checked checkbox. And returns only values of cells, there is no <tr> and <td> tags. And this removes rows from the current page.